# Error: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, vue.js

I am using Vuejs and I keep getting this warning in the console. Also no data is loaded because of this warning. I checked the code for unwanted tags but did not find any.

Is this because of the javascript code or I have something wrong in my html?

Here is my code:

> HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action=".">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="float: right;"><h4>Date:</h4>
                <input class="form-control" style="padding-bottom:0px;" type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="true" name="date" value="2016-06-30">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit" >
            </div>

        </form>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="float: right; margin-top:40px;">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="csv_export">Click to Export</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin:20px;">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" id="absent-list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Full Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Section</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Person Called</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Person Relation</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Phone Number</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Absent Reason</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">Remarks</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-show="loading" class="text-center">
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x"></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="record in absent_followback_records">

                    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;" scope="row"> {{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{record.student_name}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{record.student_section}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;">{{record.person_called}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;">{{record.person_relation}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;">{{record.phone_number}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;">{{record.absent_reason_name}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;">{{record.remarks}}</td>
                    <td  style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" v-on:click="editAbsentFollowbackRecord($index)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#absent-followback-edit"> Edit </a></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/jquery.datepick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/csrftoken.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.TableCSVExport.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var absentFollowbackListAPiUrl = "/student/api/absent/followback/list/11/";
    var absent_reason = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"model": "studentprofile.absentreason", "pk": 1, "fields": {"created": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.410Z", "modified": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.410Z", "reason_name": "sick"}}, {"model": "studentprofile.absentreason", "pk": 2, "fields": {"created": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.416Z", "modified": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.416Z", "reason_name": "arrived late"}}, {"model": "studentprofile.absentreason", "pk": 3, "fields": {"created": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.419Z", "modified": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.419Z", "reason_name": "work at home"}}, {"model": "studentprofile.absentreason", "pk": 4, "fields": {"created": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.423Z", "modified": "2016-05-08T06:09:42.423Z", "reason_name": "public holiday"}}]');
    var profile_value = false;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/student/student-followback.js"></script>
```

> absent-followback.js file

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
});

$('#csv_export').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#absent-list').TableCSVExport({
        delivery: 'download',
        filename: 'absent-list(' + $( "#datepicker" ).val() + ').csv'
    });
});

var vm = new Vue({
        el: 'body',
        data: {
            absent_followback_records: [],
            followbackRecordIndex: 'off',
            absentReasonList: absent_reason,
            loading: false,
            currentData: {},
            profile: profile_value,
            listApiUrl: absentFollowbackListAPiUrl
        },
        methods: {
            populateData: function(api_url){
                var self = this;
                $.get(api_url, function(data){
                    self.absent_followback_records = data;
                    self.loading = false;
                });
            },
            getAbsentFollowbackRecord: function () {
                var self = this;
                self.loading = true;
                var date = $( "#datepicker" ).val();
                var api_url = self.listApiUrl + '?date=' + date;
                self.populateData(api_url);
            },
            getProfileAbsentFollowbackRecord: function (event) {
                var self = this;
                self.loading = true;
                var expanded = $(event.target).attr('aria-expanded');
                if (expanded == 'false'){
                    $(event.target).html('Hide Details');
                    var studentId = $(event.target).attr('studentId');
                    var api_url = self.listApiUrl + '?student_id=' + studentId;
                    self.populateData(api_url);
                }
                else{
                    $(event.target).html('Show Details');
                }
            },
            editAbsentFollowbackRecord: function (followbackRecordIndex) {
                var self = this;
                self.currentData = self.absent_followback_records[followbackRecordIndex];
                self.followbackRecordIndex = followbackRecordIndex;
            },
            updateAbsentFollowbackRecord: function (followbackRecordIndex){
                var self = this;
                var updateData = self.currentData;
                var absent_date = updateData.date;
                var student_id = updateData.student;
                var post_url = updateData.update_url;
                var person_called = updateData.person_called;
                var person_relation = updateData.person_relation;
                var phone_number = updateData.phone_number;
                var absent_reason = updateData.absent_reason;
                var remarks = updateData.remarks;
                if (person_called){
                    var data = {
                        student: parseInt(student_id),
                        date: absent_date,
                        person_called: person_called,
                        person_relation: person_relation,
                        phone_number: phone_number,
                        absent_reason: parseInt(absent_reason),
                        remarks: remarks
                    };
                    $('#updateAbsentFollowback').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Saving').attr('class', 'btn btn-primary disabled');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: post_url,
                        type: "PUT",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function(responseData) {
                            $('#updateAbsentFollowback').html('Save').attr('class', 'btn btn-success');
                            if (self.profile == true){
                                api_url = self.listApiUrl + '?student_id=' + student_id;
                                self.populateData(api_url);
                            }
                            else{
                                self.getAbsentFollowbackRecord();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        },
        ready() {
            if (this.profile != true){
                this.getAbsentFollowbackRecord();
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you showed the compiled HTML as I don't know what {% means

Answer (score 131):

You can use script tag in this way and it will work fine.
I was facing the same problem when I used `<script></script>` tag without specifying its type.
After using the type attribute Vue did not warn me for critical error:

```html
<script type="application/javascript"> 
    // your code
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, helped with VueJS squawking for this terrible script embed 3rd party service I have to use. They used type="text/javascript". Changing it to "application/javascript" avoided the issue.

Comment: you have to check you logic @Emilie

Comment: How could you possibly know this

Comment: it was a trial, I just tried to use the standard script syntax tag for javascript inside an HTML

Comment: Thanks.. You make my day..

Comment: Doesn't work with type="application/ld+json

Comment: The question was about loading a javascript logic within vue script
to load a JSON file, you can only import it within your view. @Suzana

Answer (score 39):

I think the answer is in you question title. Just get rid of all the `<script>` tags in the template, put them outside of the template.

In this case you are using `body` as the template and you *are* putting scripts inside your template (`body`)

The easy solution is to change the `el: 'body'` to `el: '#wrapper'` and edit your html to

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
<script ... >
<script ... >
</body>
```

Comment: I have similar html file and similar script tags which is working absolutely fine. I think the problem is in the js file. I will edit and put compiled html and vue js file

Comment: And that html file has an script tag in the body too? im having the same problem but im unable to use the body because of this. Are you sure the working html has script tags in the body?

Comment: I have an unconventional exercise I'm doing where I'm exporting an SVG from Adobe Illustrator, renaming it to .html and using Vue in it to do some interactivity. While it seemed to be working ok on my other computer, I started an exercise on a different one with latest jquery and vue, and this started happening - likely to scripts inside <defs> tags (?) , anyway, I just limited by Vue portion to a group inside of my SVG.

Comment: I have to embed a google chart inside the Vue App div. Any way I can turn off the error ?

Answer (score 18):

Make sure you have a closing tag on your root element.
I just spent the last 6 hours systematically removing things and pulling my hair out. Turns out I had deleted my closing  at some point and Vue was interpreting

Comment: I have checked all the opening and closing tags in the html and all the tags properly closed. Thanks for the suggesting though, I will check them in future

Comment: This was it, ensure all tags are closed properly.

Answer (score 15):

a pair of mismatched tags (div, span) can cause this error.

```
<div id="app">
    <div>{{ a }} </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is because of script tag in your app scope. In my case it was because of google captcha that was in my scope. Google captcha iframe contains script tag

Comment: I am sorry but the truth is that wasn't google script it was other my script tag in my vue scope. Scripts in iframe don't disturb

Answer (score 3):

VueJs doesn't allow  inside the app's component. For Example,`

```
<body>
    <div id="vue-id">
        <!-- Ways of calling to templates-->
        <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
        <h2 v-text="message"></h2>
        <h3>{{ value * 5 }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ value }}</h3>

       <script></script>
    </div>    
</body>`
```

where  is inside the same [ app's component]
The right option is to include  outside the app's component`

```
<body>
    <div id="vue-id">
        <!-- Ways of calling to templates-->
        <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
        <h2 v-text="message"></h2>
        <h3>{{ value * 5 }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ value }}</h3>
    </div>
    <script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is a little specific, as I'm using Vue JS v2 in conjunction with jQuery v3.

I'm using jQuery to load the instance of my application with something simple like this:

```
$(() => {

  new Vue({
    name: 'MyApp',
    el: '#app' // which is my main HTML element for my entire page app
  });

});
```

So, this won't initiate until the entire document is loaded.

In my footer, I'm changing any offending script tags with this before the entire document is loaded, but after my closing main HTML tag:

```
$('main script:not([type="application/javascript"])').attr('type', 'application/javascript');
```

This did the trick for me without having to parse any output from offending tags and doing anything more extravagant.

This can be extrapolated out, using the native document selectors if you're not using jQuery, like my example.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit first check for mismatched/unclosed tags *within* your template, as others have said. Vue can be very picky with that)

*Might* be a simple as an explicit closure of the component's tag:

Version: vue@2.6.11

### Error there:

```
...body html...

<bme-form-projval
show_debug_elements="Y"
form_name="batchform"
>

...body html...
```

#### still there:

```
<bme-form-projval
show_debug_elements="Y"
form_name="batchform"
/>
```

### Error solved:

```
<bme-form-projval
show_debug_elements="Y"
form_name="batchform"
>

</bme-form-projval>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all HTML Tags in the page are opened and closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Although changing "script" to "script type="application/javascript"" makes the warning disappeared, it causes the page not to finish loading. Therefore, it would not be a good idea to use it!

Answer (score 0):

**This code generate this error too!**

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <div>...</div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Laravel layout) the problem was that i put the footer containing the script inside the div i.e. id="app"

Changing the placement of it outside the div solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the end of the error it will tell you how many `div's` you have to close before the vue `script`

```
2247|  </script></div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^2247|  </script></div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your browser source code, maybe something else has been added to the framework you are using.
In my case, I did not remove the rails layout template.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).