# Vue error "Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI."

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm using Django webpack-loader to load VueJS components inside of my Django templates, basically i have the following django template:

**myTemplate.html** (this is the Django template from where i call vue)

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

    <div id="someDjangoStuff">
      ...
    </div>

    <formComponent></formComponent>
    <anotherVueComponent></anotherVueComponent>
    
    <div id="someDjangoStuff2">
      ...
    </div>

    </div>
<body>

{% endblock %}

</html>
```

The components are basic forms, like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
        
    <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit()">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="amount">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="price">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    
     </form>
  </div>

</template>
```

So basically what i'm doing here is:

1. I load a Django template
2. I load the Vue app with `<div id="app"></div>`
3. Instead of loading the whole Vue app, i only load the components i need, and inside the `<div id="app"></div>` i load other html too.

The problem is that, in my console, i'll get the following errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.
```

I'm sure it's because i'm loading the Vue app and inside the app i'm also loading other html tags. Now this error doesn't have any repercussion, this setup seems to work fine except, but i have some doubts on if this is the right way to use Vue or not.

1. Is there any way to suppress the error or do this in another way without getting the errors?
2. Can it create problems because it's not how i should use Vue?

Comment: What are your ```someVueComponent``` and ```anotherVueComponent``` codes?

Comment: It's very basic components that only have some HTML, but they don't have any script or stuff that could cause the error

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119088/error-templates-should-only-be-responsible-for-mapping-the-state-to-the-ui-avo/

Comment: Your error seems like that you are manipulating state without committing the updates. you need to read more about Vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alright!

#### if you would like to use Vue components outside Vue compiled app context, then you need to:

- include runTimeCompiler in vue config and note this will increase your build roughly 200kb

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

- don't render the JS app upon build

```js
// main.js
// Vue 2 
new Vue({
  el:"#app",

  // render: h => h(App) that what triggers your build error
  render: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'?h => h(App):'' //render only while testing
});

// Vue3
const app = createApp({})
app.mount('#app')

// don't forget to register global components
```

- inside your base template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% load webpack_static from webpack_loader %}
{% render_bundle 'app' 'css' %}
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% render_bundle 'app' 'js' %}
    {% render_bundle 'chunk-vendors' 'js' %}

</body>
</html>
```

- then normally extend from base template Django as usual

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<your-lovely-vue-component></your-lovely-vue-component>
{% endblock %}
```

### and for completeness:

You may not use django-webpack-loader at all and depend on collectstatic command, just include your vue app path inside django settings.TEMPLATES.DIRS and set filenameHashing to false in vue.config.js.

However I use the package personally and works well, note webpack-bundle-tracker latest version has some problems and I recommend ^0.4.3 .

The following video doesn't say exactly like that but somewhere you will get better understanding in integrating Vue with MVC frameworks.
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-vue-3/episodes/14

### Cheers

Comment: This was a very helpful answer! Thank you a lot! If i'm allowed to, i have a question: so in this case i'm loading the vue app in this HMTL page, which is a page in my django project. Now suppose i need to use Vue in another page of the same project: should i create a new vue app or is it fine to use the same app but with only the components i need? Of course i'm not using it for SPA

Comment: So the TL;DR is: is it fine to load the same Vue app across different Django templates but in each page i load only the components i need for that page?

Comment: as long as you don't need spa then don't render the app, and you can use it as many as you want because you included run time compiler already just extend the base template in Django. in other words you got vue app ready to manipulate your DOM inside Django template. and yes if you want still use spa just render on another DOM element id and you can create apps as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Vue components inside a Django template like that. You need to put all Vue code in a JS file, and then import the JS file into Django.

In your Django template you might have a container like

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

And in your Vue code you'll attach the vue application to that container like:

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

In the django template you don't put any Vue code at all. It all needs to be in Vue, and then a linked javascript file will insert all the relevant code inside the container.

On a side note, `django-webpack-loader` is no longer maintained. I have created a package to replace it called [django-manifest-loader](https://github.com/shonin/django-manifest-loader) that will fulfil your needs. Unfortunately I haven't written about using it with Vue, but if you're using webpack, most of the documentation will hold. [Blog post walking you through setup is here](https://shonin.medium.com/django-and-webpack-now-work-together-seamlessly-a90cffdbab8e)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! What's the difference with what i'm doing? In my template, i have a <div id="app"></div>, just like you said, but instead of rendering the whole vue app, i only render specific components in the places where i need them, and i'm already attaching the application to the container like you mentioned

Comment: Webpack-loader not beint maintained is a problem indeed, i'm glad you are providing a solution! Are you planning to create a guide for Vue in the future? I would like to move to manifest but i'm afraid i might break something in my setup

Comment: @Jack022 you need more specific help than Stackoverflow can provide. You can't render specific parts of a vue app. The Vue app is a complete unit, you either embed it into Django or not. the entire Vue app is mounted to the div, and you cannot embed Vue tags inside the Django template. I'll leave another comment when I write a tutorial for Django/Vue. There should be nothing inside <div id="app"></div>

Comment: So basically what i'm doing wrong is only adding other tags inside the <div id="app"></div>, while i should only have <div id="app"></div> or <div id="app"><someVueComponent /></div>?