# Vue 3 warning "tags with side effects" is breaking Production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've recently upgraded from Vue 2 to Vue 3, and there are a few parts of my app that in `development` mode give the warning:

> [Vue warn]: Template compilation error: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates.

In Vue 2, these warnings were just hidden in `production`. However, in Vue 3, pages with these warnings completely break and the screen goes blank. They run fine in `development`.

It's not practical for me to remove all of these `<script>` tags because they are inserted dynamically by my CMS (Shopify).

Is there any way for me to catch these errors in production so they don't take down my site?

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109131). Could you provide your HTML markup or components where these scripts are inserted to? and how it looks before the insert and after.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So far, this is the best solution I've found.

Replace:

```
<script>
  // JS CODE HERE
</script>
```

With:

```
<component :is="'script'">
  // JS Here
</component>
```

However, I'd prefer a global setting so that I don't have to do this for every plugin. Right now my app feels very brittle in case anyone on my team adds another CMS plugin.

I don't want the app just breaking as soon as it comes across a `<script>` tag...

Comment: This also works for style tags as well.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I move id="app" attribute  from `<body>`  to  first `<div>` then solved the problem

before:

```
<body id="app">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

after:

```
<body>
   <div id="app">
     ...
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me using Vue3

Answer (score 8):

it's a bit late but the same thing happened to me and I think I have the solution. At least in my case.

You have to embed the script just before the closing body tag in your index.html. The problem is (I imagine) that you have it inside the main div.

It should look like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, there was a div tag that wasn't closed. so I closed it and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed `script` and `style` tags in your templates using [`postscribe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postscribe)

```js
npm install --save postscribe

// then
<template>
  <div id="script-placeholder" />
</template>

<script>
import postscribe from 'postscribe'

export default {
  mounted() {
    postscribe('#script-placeholder', '<script src="/path/to/script/src.js"><\/script>')
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app, the suggested solutions didn't work, but I figured out from an app that did work that, the warning goes away if the Vue app component that I'm mounting has a non-empty template.

```
createApp({ }).mount(somewhere);  // warning
createApp({ template: `` }).mount(somewhere);  // warning
createApp({ template: `4` }).mount(somewhere);  // goes away
```

My "app" was a single HTML file with  and subsequent script elements.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34942846)

Answer (score 0):

This as well works well for me, I see it also affects the style tag

```
<component :is="'style'">

    CS here

</component>
```